# How to keep fake browser tab focus on multiple tabs?

Tags: javascript, selenium, browser

I would like to make my browser faking the focus on multiple tabs/windows for testing purposes. I am testing pages that require the user focus (to be an active windows/tab). Is there a way to fake it? Different browser? Plugin? JavaScript code I can run from console? A use of the Selenium?

I would like to run the solution in multiple tabs/windows while I am doing other jobs on my pc - coding, browsing etc.

The preferable solution should work on Ubuntu, but Windows 10 is also acceptable (a cross-platform solution would be the best).

Note: else it would be nice to run without headless mode, so I can interact with content in some cases manully.

Comment: You can run selenium script with headless mode.

Comment: @Yun Fair point, I added a note at the end of my quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

More explanations: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/39547/selenium-how-to-prevent-a-just-started-chrome-window-from-receiving-focus

You could run this in a virtual machine to retain interactability without interrupting your work.